# InAppBrowser issue in iOS

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser, whitelist

I've been searching for solutions to my issue for around a week now, with no luck.

We have a Phonegap project, where we are using InAppBrowser to display videos and games which are being served over the internet.

In Android, I am getting the expected behaviour - the IABrowser loads, the script and styles get injected.

However, in iOS, the IABrowser loads (I can see it via Safari on my computer), but opens in the background, even when hidden is explicitly set as no. Even when I'm opening the IABrowser with hidden set to yes and calling the .show() method, the window doesn't open.

There's a twist here - if I open the app afresh, connect to my PC and run the window.open() command with the same options from Safari's **console**, it works fine. Apparently it's only not working as expected when the command is run from the app's javascript.

Has anyone ever faced anything like this? Any pointers to what I might be doing wrong?